# @LocatorApplication starts and then immediately stops

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-gemfire

Everything seems to be created fine but once it finishes initializing everything it just stops.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@LocatorApplication
public class ServerApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Log:

```
2020-08-03 10:59:18.250  INFO 7712 --- [           main] o.a.g.d.i.InternalLocator                : Locator started on 10.25.209.139[8081]
2020-08-03 10:59:18.250  INFO 7712 --- [           main] o.a.g.d.i.InternalLocator                : Starting server location for Distribution Locator on LB183054.dmn1.fmr.com[8081]
2020-08-03 10:59:18.383  INFO 7712 --- [           main] c.f.g.l.LocatorSpringApplication         : Started LocatorSpringApplication in 8.496 seconds (JVM running for 9.318)
2020-08-03 10:59:18.385  INFO 7712 --- [m shutdown hook] o.a.g.d.i.InternalDistributedSystem      : VM is exiting - shutting down distributed system
2020-08-03 10:59:18.395  INFO 7712 --- [m shutdown hook] o.a.g.i.c.GemFireCacheImpl               : GemFireCache[id = 1329087972; isClosing = true; isShutDownAll = false; created = Mon Aug 03 10:59:15 EDT 2020; server = false; copyOnRead = false; lockLease = 120; lockTimeout = 60]: Now closing.
2020-08-03 10:59:18.416  INFO 7712 --- [m shutdown hook] o.a.g.d.i.ClusterDistributionManager     : Shutting down DistributionManager 10.25.209.139(locator1:7712:locator)<ec><v0>:41000. 
2020-08-03 10:59:18.517  INFO 7712 --- [m shutdown hook] o.a.g.d.i.ClusterDistributionManager     : Now closing distribution for 10.25.209.139(locator1:7712:locator)<ec><v0>:41000
2020-08-03 10:59:18.518  INFO 7712 --- [m shutdown hook] o.a.g.d.i.m.g.Services                   : Stopping membership services
2020-08-03 10:59:18.518  INFO 7712 --- [ip View Creator] o.a.g.d.i.m.g.Services                   : View Creator thread is exiting
2020-08-03 10:59:18.520  INFO 7712 --- [Server thread 1] o.a.g.d.i.m.g.Services                   : GMSHealthMonitor server thread exiting
2020-08-03 10:59:18.536  INFO 7712 --- [m shutdown hook] o.a.g.d.i.ClusterDistributionManager     : DistributionManager stopped in 120ms.
2020-08-03 10:59:18.537  INFO 7712 --- [m shutdown hook] o.a.g.d.i.ClusterDistributionManager     : Marking DistributionManager 10.25.209.139(locator1:7712:locator)<ec><v0>:41000 as closed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior, OOTB.

Most Apache Geode processes (clients (i.e. `ClientCache`), `Locators`, *Managers* and "peer" `Cache` nodes/members of a cluster/distributed system) only create daemon Threads (i.e. non-blocking Threads).  Therefore, the Apache Geode JVM process will startup, initialize itself and then shutdown immediately.

Only an Apache Geode `CacheServer` process (a "peer" `Cache` that has a `CacheServer` component to listen for client connections), starts and continues to run.  That is because the `ServerSocket` used to listen for client `Socket` connections is created on a non-daemon Thread (i.e. blocking Thread), which prevents the JVM process from shutting down.  Otherwise, a `CacheServer` would fall straight through as well.

You might be thinking, well, how does *Gfsh* prevent `Locators` (i.e. using the `start locator` command) and "servers" (i.e. using the `start server` command) from shutting down?

> NOTE: By default, *Gfsh* creates a `CacheServer` instance when starting a GemFire/Geode server using the `start server` command.  The `CacheServer` component of the "server" can be **disabled** by specifying the `--disable-default-server` option to the `start server` command. In this case, this "server" will not be able to serve clients.  Still the peer node/member will continue to run, but not without extra help.  See [here](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/112/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/start.html#topic_3764EE2DB18B4AE4A625E0354471738A) for more details on the `start server` *Gfsh* command.

So, how does *Gfsh* prevent the processes from falling through?

Under-the-hood, *Gfsh* uses the [`LocatorLauncher`](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/distributed/LocatorLauncher.html) and [`ServerLauncher`](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/distributed/ServerLauncher.html) classes to configure and fork the JVM processes to launch `Locators` and *servers*, respectively.

By way of example, [here](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.12.0/geode-gfsh/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/management/internal/cli/commands/StartLocatorCommand.java#L208-L210) is *Gfsh's* `start locator` command using the `LocatorLauncher` class.  Technically, it uses the configuration from the `LocatorLauncher` class instance to [construct](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.12.0/geode-gfsh/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/management/internal/cli/commands/StartLocatorCommand.java#L219-L221) (and specifically, [here](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.12.0/geode-gfsh/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/management/internal/cli/commands/StartLocatorCommand.java#L451-L513)) the `java` command-line used to [fork and launch](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.12.0/geode-gfsh/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/management/internal/cli/commands/StartLocatorCommand.java#L223-L224) (and specifically, [here](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.12.0/geode-gfsh/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/management/internal/cli/commands/StartLocatorCommand.java#L351-L355)) a separate JVM process.

However, the key here is the specific "command" passed to the `LocatorLauncher` class when starting the `Locator`, which is the `START` command ([here](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.12.0/geode-gfsh/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/management/internal/cli/commands/StartLocatorCommand.java#L482)).

In the `LocatorLauncher` class, we see that the `START` command does the following, from the [main method](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.12.0/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/distributed/LocatorLauncher.java#L215), to the [run method](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.12.0/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/distributed/LocatorLauncher.java#L620-L623), it [starts](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.12.0/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/distributed/LocatorLauncher.java#L621) the `Locator`, then [`waitsOnLocator`](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.12.0/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/distributed/LocatorLauncher.java#L622) (with [implementation](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.12.0/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/distributed/LocatorLauncher.java#L814)).

Without the wait, the `Locator` would fall straight through as you are experiencing.

You can simulate the same effect (i.e. "falling straight through") using the following code, which uses the Apache Geode API to configure and launch a Locator (in-process).

```
public class ApacheGeodeLocatorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LocatorLauncher locatorLauncher = new LocatorLauncher.Builder()
            .set("jmx-manager", "true")
            .set("jmx-manager-port", "0")
            .set("jmx-manager-start", "true")
            .setMemberName("ApacheGeodeBasedLocator")
            .setPort(0)
            .build();

        locatorLauncher.start();

        //locatorLauncher.waitOnLocator();
    }
}
```

This simple little program will fall straight through.  However, if you uncomment `locatorLaucncher.waitOnLocator()`, then the JVM process will block.

This is not unlike what SDG's [`LocatorFactoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/LocatorFactoryBean.html) class (see [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/2.3.2.RELEASE/spring-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/LocatorFactoryBean.java)) is doing actually.  It, too, uses the `LocatorLauncher` class to configure and bootstrap a `Locator` in-process.  The `LocatorFactoryBean` is the class used to configure and bootstrap a `Locator` when declaring the SDG `@LocatorApplication` annotation on your `@SpringBootApplication` class.

However, I do think there is room for improvement, here.  Therefore, I have filed [DATAGEODE-361](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGEODE-361).

In the meantime, and as a workaround, you can achieve the same effect of a blocking `Locator` by having a look at the *Smoke Test* for the same in ***Spring Boot for Apache Geode*** (SBDG) project.  See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/blob/1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-geode-tests/smoke-tests/locator-application/src/main/java/example/app/geode/locator/SpringBootApacheGeodeLocatorApplication.java#L46-L75).

However, after DATAGEODE-361 is complete, the extra logic preventing the `Locator` JVM process from shutting down will no longer be necessary.

Comment: UPDATE: See comment in DATAGEODE-361 (https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGEODE-361?focusedCommentId=189754&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-189754).

Comment: UPDATE: See next comment in DATAGEODE-361 (https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGEODE-361?focusedCommentId=189760&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-189760).

Comment: Same question for @ClientCacheApplication.  How do I get it so it doesn't run right through?

Comment: Same answer as above.  Also second paragraph beginning with "_Most Apache Geode processes (clients..._".  Although, I would say that for "client" applications, typically most users are creating some sort of Spring Boot, Web Application, which will  naturally block (whether embedded or not). However, there are all sorts of client-side applications for different purposes (e.g. Web, Batch, etc), so, technically, I'd prefer to leave this concern up to the developer(s) of the application since they would know the lifecycle of the app the best.

Comment: Think of a client-side, Spring Boot/Apache Geode or VMware GemFire application exactly the same as a SQL database application using a JDBC Driver.  The JDBC Driver does not cause your application to block and halt the JVM process from shutting down.  A GemFire/Geode `ClientCache` is the "driver" in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry has been a long week.  All I had to do was a the web dependency.  Cheers!

Comment: No problem.  Clients are usually easier to deal with.  The Locator (and servers in general) are bit of a different story.  I will continue to provide some guidance and  relief here (for Locators anyway) as part of DATAGEODE-361.  For more info, just follow along in the comments on the JIRA ticket.  I will try to keep the ticket up-to-date as I progress.  Should have something by the next set of releases: SD Moore (2.2.x), SD Neumann (2.3.x) and SD Ockham (2.4.x); see here: https://spring-calendar.cfapps.io/. Cheers!